# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findByIdAndUpdate' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, backend, mern

Related Schema:

```
{
    qtitle:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    descofq:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    answers:[
        {
            answer:{
                type:String
            },
            likes:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:"USER"}]
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

Backend:

```
router.put('/answer/like',authenticate,(req,res)=>{
    Question.findById(req.body.quesId).then(question=>{
        question.answers.answer.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.ansId,{
            $push:{likes:req.rootUser._id}
        },{
            new:true
        }).exec((err,result)=>{
            if(err){
                return res.status(422).json({errror:err})
            }else{
                res.json(result)
            }
        })
         
})
})
```

quesId and ansId are coming from the frontend part.

frontend code:

```
const likePost = (id)=>{
        fetch('/answer/like',{
            method:"put",
            headers:{
            Accept:"application/json",
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
        },
            body:JSON.stringify({
              quesId:ques._id,
                ansId:id
            })
        }).then(res=>res.json())
        .then(result=>{
          console.log(ques)
            const newData = ques.map(Q=>{
                if(Q.answers._id===result._id){
                    return result
                }else{
                    return ques
                }
            })
            setQues(newData)
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
      }
```

Through id I'm passing ans._id.

error:
[image]

Problem : I think I can't access answers.answer through ID, is it because answers is an array or there is a problem in frontend part, please help.

Comment: If `question` is the document returned by `findById`, what does `question.answers.answer` contain?

Comment: @joe actually it should be question.answers and it will contain array of objects which have id's , but question.anwser is also giving error

Comment: If `answers` is an array, shouldn't you be iterating it?

Comment: @Phil can i not iterate it and if I want to, is there any way?